# Scala Slick generic table trait move out of DAO

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have currently this code:

```
class UsersRepository @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import driver.api._

  private val Users = TableQuery[UsersTable]

  def findByName(name: String): Future[Option[User]] =
    db.run(Users.filter(_.name === name).take(1).result.headOption)

  implicit val localDateTimeColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[LocalDateTime, Timestamp](
    d => Timestamp.from(d.toInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(0))),
    d => d.toLocalDateTime
  )

  trait GenericTable {
    this: Table[_] =>
    def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def createdAt = column[LocalDateTime]("created_at")
    def updatedAt = column[LocalDateTime]("updated_at")
  }

  private class UsersTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "User") with GenericTable {

    def name = column[String]("name")
    def url = column[String]("url")

    def nameIndex = index("name_index", name, unique = true)

    override def * = (id, createdAt, updatedAt, name, url) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
  }

}
```

How can I now easily move the GenericTable trait out of the UsersRepository so that I can use it with other tables? If I just move it out, then things like `column`, `Table` and `O` are not found anymore, because I loose the things from the driver import.

I also would like to move the `UsersTable` definition itself out of the DAO/repository class. I have the same problem in this case.

Thanks,
Magnus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provider `dbConfig` in the trait as a no input parameter `def`

```
trait GenericTableProvider {
  val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]
  import dbConfig.driver.api._

  trait GenericTable {
      this: Table[_] =>

      def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
      def createdAt = column[LocalDateTime]("created_at")
      def updatedAt = column[LocalDateTime]("updated_at")
    }

}
```

and then use it as shown in the code snippet below.

```
class UsersRepository @Inject()(protected override val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) 
  extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] 
  with GenericTableProvider {

  import driver.api._

  private val Users = TableQuery[UsersTable]

  private class UsersTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "User") with GenericTable {

    def name = column[String]("name")
    def url = column[String]("url")

    def nameIndex = index("name_index", name, unique = true)

    override def * = (id, createdAt, updatedAt, name, url) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
  }
  .....

 }
```

override `def dbConfigProvider` with a `val dbConfigProvider`

Comment: Unfortunately, this still does not work, because in the line `this: Table[_] =>` symbol table cannot be found. I am also unable to move the import statement before this line.

Comment: @Magnus edited the answer ... with some fixes .. please check .. hope this helps

Comment: Yes, that helps, thank you! I ended up implementing it a little different. `UsersRepository` extends `GenericTableProvider` (because I do not want it to be a `Table`). But inside `UsersRepository` I can then easily use the `GenericTable`  trait for my actual inner `UsersTable` class :)